# How to create package with custom symbols (i.e. glyphs)

Tags: symbols, packages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a symbol font from SVG symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22487/create-a-symbol-font-from-svg-symbols)

I want to create a package for myself, that prints custom glyphs (some glyphs for instance that I made up). How do I go with this? I see there're many packages with, for instance, Egyptian glyphs. How are they created? Can you give me step-bystep, something like:

1. I need to draw all the symbols in .png or some vector format
2. I need to use some software to bind this symbols to commands and put it in package
3. Use it in LaTeX file

Thank for any help!

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to create a *font*, not just a package.  You want to look at metafont for that.

Comment: The question this one has been duped to mentions SVG, but the same approach would apply to any other vector format. (I would not recommend making bitmap-based fonts or symbols.)