# Typesetting Babylonian numerals?

Tags: fonts, symbols

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`babyloniannum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babyloniannum)

I would like to typeset Babylonian numerals as shown e.g. on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_numerals). Ideally I would like a command where I can type something like `$\babylonian{42}$` and get it to produce the appropriate symbol, but I will be also happy if there is a font or something where I can get the symbols and then stack them together myself.

Is there anything for this already implemented?

[image: examples of Babylonian numerals]

Comment: A quick search on Google found: [This](http://www.sron.nl/~jheise/akkadian/cf_fonts.html)

Comment: There's a section of the symbols guide that lists some ancient scripts pacakges. No Babylonian numeral package, but some of the Linear A symbols get close...

Comment: Two more links from a Google for "CTAN Cuneiform": [ugarite](http://ctan.sqsol.co.uk/fonts/archaic/ugarite/tryugarite.pdf) and [piska](http://www-hep2.fzu.cz/~piska/cuneiform/piska.pdf)

Comment: My laptop is very slow compiling LaTeX, but _extremely_ slow compiling XeTeX, so for me, the latter is not an option. However, I managed to do two ugly hacks that are good enough for my purposes: $\stackon[-3pt]{$\text{l}$}{$\text{v}$}$  % Babylonian one; AND %$\big\langle \!\!\scriptstyle {\text{|}}$ % Babylonian ten

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a paleo-babylonian font [on this page](http://www.hethport.uni-wuerzburg.de/cuneifont/). Using `fontspec` with XeTeX or LuaTex and things like `\char"1240D`, you could easily typeset what you need.

Here is a quick example for XeTeX.

**Note**: It turns out that the font doc is wrong (Ah! If they used TeX to generate it...) and 9 is actually mapped at `1240E`, quite logically. Also, 20 seems to be missing while 30 is mapped several times for some reason, so I'm doing 20 with 2 "10" glyphs and a bit of kerning. I'm also adjust kerning between tens and units.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{numname}

\newcommand{\babydisp}[1]{%
  \fontspec{Santakku}{\char"#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\babynum}[1]{%
\numdigits{#1}%
\ifcase\c@xsm@mctr
  \or
  \babydisp{1230B} %10
  \or
  \babydisp{1230B}\kern-1.5pt{}\babydisp{1230B} %20 -- unknown?
  \or
  \babydisp{1230D} %30
  \or
  \babydisp{1240F} %40
  \or
  \babydisp{12410} %50
\fi
\kern-4pt{}%
\ifcase\c@ism@mctr
  \or
  \babydisp{12079} %1
  \or
  \babydisp{1222B} %2
  \or
  \babydisp{12408} %3
  \or
  \babydisp{120FB} %4
  \or
  \babydisp{1240A} %5
  \or
  \babydisp{1240B} %6
  \or
  \babydisp{1240C} %7
  \or
  \babydisp{1240D} %8
  \or
  \babydisp{1240E} %9
\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%\noindent\foreach \n in {1,...,59}{%
%\n\quad\babynum{\n}\\
%}

\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\noindent\foreach \n in {1,...,20}{%
\n\quad\babynum{\n}\\
}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\noindent\foreach \n in {21,...,40}{%
\n\quad\babynum{\n}\\
}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\noindent\foreach \n in {41,...,59}{%
\n\quad\babynum{\n}\\
}
\end{minipage} \hfill

\end{document}
```

[image: babylonian with adjusted kerning]

**Edit:** There is now a package [on CTAN](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/xetex/latex/babyloniannum), so you can use it as follows:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{minimal}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{babyloniannum}


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\noindent\foreach \n in {1,...,20}{%
\n\quad\babyloniannum{\n}\\
}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\noindent\foreach \n in {21,...,40}{%
\n\quad\babyloniannum{\n}\\
}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\noindent\foreach \n in {41,...,59}{%
\n\quad\babyloniannum{\n}\\
}
\end{minipage} \hfill

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Version 0.4 of the package allows to typeset numbers beyond 59 (up to 60^9 = 1.0077696 × 10^16 in theory, although I think TeX will give up before that).

Comment: Note that there is a `\ifcase<number> <zero>\or <one>\or <two>\or ...\else <else> \fi` in TeX.

Comment: Thanks @Martin. I updated my answer accordingly. That said, I think this should work with a modulo at some point.

Comment: I would also put the `\ifnum` into the `\else` clause of `\ifcase`.

Comment: Also, please mention that you need to use XeLaTeX for this solution.

Comment: Ok, done. How could I actually calculate a modulo? I know `mod()` in tikz, but can I do that outside of tikz?

Comment: @Raphink check out how something like [numname](http://az.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/numname) deals with bigger numbers...

Comment: You can make an integer devision and then subtract the result from the original value to get the modulo.

Comment: @Seamus: interesting. Maybe it's just me, but I find it scary how simple things in most computer languages look freaky in TeX.

Comment: @Martin: I find that it's very hard to find doc on how to perform operations in TeX, since most results explain how to typeset the operations rather than perform them.

Comment: @Seamus: Actually, I'm going to make use of the `\numdigits` function from `numname` since it does the job already.

Comment: @Raphink You might also consider using the much more sophisticated [fmtcount](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fmtcount) package...

Comment: The font doc turns out to be wrong, 9 is mapped at 1240E, quite logically...

Comment: @Seamus: well `\numdigits` returns what I need :-)

Comment: Awesome work! Thanks Raphink and all others who helped building this great answer!

Comment: @Juan: the package is already on CTAN: http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/xetex/latex/babyloniannum

Comment: This is why I love this site. Don't forget to add this package to http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/who-are-the-package-maintainers-here `;-)`

Comment: It would be great if the package supported bold font...

Comment: @Jay PR welcome https://github.com/raphink/babylonian

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia also has the two needed symbols as SVG vector graphics:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Babylonian_1.svg
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Babylonian_10.svg

You can turn them rather easily to PDF using e.g. `inkscape --export-pdf=<pdf> <svg>`. Then position them in the shown way for all numbers from 1-59. For larger numbers you would need to add some loop.

It is also possible to make your own font as shown in [Create a symbol font from SVG symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22487/create-a-symbol-font-from-svg-symbols).