# Looking for fancy but easily handwritten typeface for mathematics with support for both uppercase and lowercase letters

Tags: fonts

I write proofs by hand. So, it would be nice to have a one-to-one correspondence between the symbols I handwrite, and the symbols in my pdf files. Thus, what I'm looking for is a fancy but easily handwritten typeface for mathematics, something along the lines of the powerset symbol `\wp`.

Now 'fancy' as it is used here is a technical term. Definition: easily distinguished from the default LaTeX mathematical typeface when displayed on the screen, and easily distinguished from the normal symbols when handwritten.

Furthermore, it should support both uppercase and lowercase letters, like the `\mathfrak` typeface. (However, Fraktur is difficult to draw by hand and therefore unsuitable for my purposes).

Does anyone know of such a thing?

Comment: Hi, it's very difficult to understand what do you _ask_ for without any insight in what do you _need_ it for. Can you tell us what purpose should it serve?

Comment: @tohecz, yes, sure. If we use lowercase letters to denote elements of sets, and upper case letters to denote the sets themselves, then I want a different typeface altogether to denote functions. I was thinking: functions that accept elements will be uppercase, and functions that accept sets will be lowercase.

Comment: I didn't mean that. You say: _"(However, Fraktur is difficult to draw by hand and therefore unsuitable for my purposes)."_ So what are the porposes? Why should printing and drawing by hand be similar? Or do I miss something completely?

Comment: @tohecz, I write proofs by hand. So it would be nice to have a one-to-one correspondence between the symbols I handwrite, and the symbols in my pdf files. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, it does. I cannot really provide an answer, just 2 suggestions: 1) Look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28340/handwritten-font-with-math-support which may do what you seek. 2) I think it's a bit "silly" (please don't take me literally, I don't know a better word to express my feeling of it) to want to unify printed and handwritten font; students/readers are clever enough to switch between these two, they have to do it all the time during math talks using both slides and a blackboard.

Comment: You could use "blackboard bold" (`\mathbb`) perhaps?

Comment: @tohecz, thank you for your input. I modified the opening statement of the question to clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: @JohnWickerson, thank you, that is very nearly suitable. The problem is, some of the lowercase letters can't be handwritten. Like the lowercase 'f'. .... There is also an issue with some of the letters having a pre-existing meaning, like 'R'. That being said, I may still end up using this in the end.

Comment: there are some suggestions in [Handwritten font with math support](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28340/579) that might be useful.

Comment: If you want `\mathbb` with lowercase letters, the [`bbm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bbm) package might be helpful.

Comment: `\mathcal{}` only works for uppercase but isn't too difficult to draw by hand.  Are you not using standard math notation?  Otherwise, `LaTeX` and `TeX` should have all the notations you desired that you can do by hand.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like "blackboard bold" might be what you're after. Usually it appears only in uppercase, but it is actually available in lowercase too, via the `bbm` package. Table 213 (page 68) of the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbols list](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) suggests it as one of several possibilities.

[image]

Comment: the stix fonts contain lowercase blackboard bold, as well as lowercase script.  release of the latex support package is imminent.  this collection hasn't yet been incorporated into the comprehensive symbols list.  (and it will probably take some time to get there, since it's such a large collection.)