# Environment with handwritten font with math support

Tags: fonts, math-mode, environments

Environment with handwritten font.

I would like to customize an environment called solution as follows.

- that had the following characteristic proof environment: input  "**\solution[of Jhon]**" output "**Solution of Jhon.**" with the same source document.
- who had a handwritten fonts such as those packages in [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html)
- that the source of the document and other environments remain unchanged.
- As in the answer to question "[Handwritten font with math support](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28340/handwritten-font-with-math-support)" I wish there was also support for the math mode.

The intention is to use sources well in solving Calculus for my students.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> that had the following characteristic proof environment: input `\solution[of Jhon]` output `Solution of Jhon.` with the same source document.

I'm not sure what you're asking here. You can use

```
\def\solution[#1]{Solution #1.}
```

to do that, but you use the word 'environment', so I think you might want (using LaTeX3)

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{solution}{o}{\textbf{Solution\IfValueTF{#1}{ #1}{}. }}{}
```

You can add further formatting commands to this as per the usual definition of an environment.

> who had a handwritten fonts such as those packages in [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html)

On each font page, there's a list of 'Style examples'; before each style there is a command which switches to that font. For example, to use the `JD` font, use `\ECFJD`. You can add this to the definition of the `solution` environment above.

> As in the answer to question "[Handwritten font with math support](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28340/handwritten-font-with-math-support)" I wish there was also support for the math mode.

None of these handwritten fonts has the symbols needed for typesetting mathematics; for mathematics, you're limited to

- The maths fonts in the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html),
- [OpenType Maths Fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Mathematical_OpenType_typefaces), which you should load using the [`unicode-math`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) package, which will require compiling with XeTeX, or
- using a normal TrueType or OpenType handwritten font (there are hundreds on the internet), loading it using the [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package, and using it as the maths font with the [`mathspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathspec) package, which will also require compiling with XeTeX.

Comment: @Chiss Thank you for appreciating my question and give me an answer. I use the $\latex 2 \epsilon $. I will try to apply the resources available in your answer to solve my problem. If I have a reasonable success  surely you are a strong candidate to receive the bonus. Thank you.