# Math versions and bm

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I am wondering how one can tell the `bm` package what `\mathversion` it should use.  Using the example of [Using \DeclareMathVersion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/using-declaremathversion)

```
\documentclass{article}
%%% text fonts
\renewcommand\rmdefault{txr}
\newcommand\gmfamily{\fontfamily{mdugm}\selectfont}

%%% New math versions
\DeclareMathVersion{varnormal}
\DeclareMathVersion{varbold}
\newcommand\txmath{\mathversion{normal}}
\newcommand\txboldmath{\mathversion{bold}}
\newcommand\mdmath{\mathversion{varnormal}}
\newcommand\mdboldmath{\mathversion{varbold}}

%%% Math symbol fonts
%%% some examples only
% Math letters from txfonts and mdugm
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{normal}{OML}{txmi}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{bold}{OML}{txmi}{bx}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{varnormal}{OML}{mdugm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{varbold}{OML}{mdugm}{b}{it}
% Math operators
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{normal}{OT1}{txr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{txr}{bx}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{varnormal}{OT1}{mdugm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{varbold}{OT1}{mdugm}{b}{n}
% Math symbols
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{normal}{OMS}{txsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{bold}{OMS}{txsy}{bx}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{varnormal}{OMS}{mdugm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{varbold}{OMS}{mdugm}{b}{n}
% Large symbols
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{txex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{txex}{bx}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{varnormal}{OMX}{mdugm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{varbold}{OMX}{mdugm}{b}{n}

%%% Math alphabets, at most 16 families
%%% some examples only
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{normal}{OT1}{txr}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{bold}{OT1}{txr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{varnormal}{OT1}{mdugm}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{varbold}{OT1}{mdugm}{b}{n}

\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{normal}{OT1}{txr}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{bold}{OT1}{txr}{bx}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{varnormal}{OT1}{mdugm}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{varbold}{OT1}{mdugm}{b}{it}

\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

This is Times font. $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. Math font
\[
  \sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0
\]
and bold math font
{\txboldmath\[
  \sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0
\]}
\[
  \bm{\sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0}
\]


\gmfamily\mdmath
This is Garamond font. $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. Math font
\[
  \sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0
\]
and bold math font
{\mdboldmath\[
  \sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0
\]}
\[
  \bm{\sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0}
\]

\end{document}
```

where I would like to have the `\mdmath` tell the `\bm` package where to find bold variants of the current font (as opposed to using `bold` which picks up Times).

Comment: If you told it the version was `heavy`, then you could use the built-in support for this. (Unless you also need `heavy`, of course.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### *Know this: I do not know what I am doing...*

## *Caveat emptor...*

This uses the **bm** package to manage bold fonts for Times and the **varbm** package to manage bold fonts for Garamond. `varbm.sty` is just like `bm.sty` except that it works with the `varbold` maths version rather than the `bold` version. It does not, however, include anything corresponding to the support for `heavy` maths in `bm.sty`.

First, an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
%% text fonts
\renewcommand\rmdefault{txr}
\newcommand\gmfamily{\fontfamily{mdugm}\selectfont}

%% New math versions
\DeclareMathVersion{varnormal}
\DeclareMathVersion{varbold}
\makeatletter
\newif\iftx@math
\newif\ifmd@math
\newcommand\txmath{%
  \mathversion{normal}%
  \ifmd@math
    \global\let\bm\oldbm
  \fi
  \tx@mathtrue
  \md@mathfalse
  \global\let\oldvarbm\varbm
  \global\let\varbm\bm}
\newcommand\mdmath{%
  \mathversion{varnormal}%
  \iftx@math
    \global\let\varbm\oldvarbm
  \fi
  \md@mathtrue
  \tx@mathfalse
  \global\let\oldbm\bm
  \global\let\bm\varbm}
\AtBeginDocument{\txmath}
\makeatother
\newcommand\varboldmath{\mathversion{varbold}}

% these commands should not be needed and are here just for comparison
\newcommand\txboldmath{\mathversion{bold}}
\newcommand\mdboldmath{\mathversion{varbold}}

%% Math symbol fonts
%% some examples only
%% Math letters from txfonts and mdugm
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{normal}{OML}{txmi}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{bold}{OML}{txmi}{bx}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{varnormal}{OML}{mdugm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{varbold}{OML}{mdugm}{b}{it}
%% Math operators
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{normal}{OT1}{txr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{txr}{bx}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{varnormal}{OT1}{mdugm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{varbold}{OT1}{mdugm}{b}{n}
%% Math symbols
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{normal}{OMS}{txsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{bold}{OMS}{txsy}{bx}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{varnormal}{OMS}{mdugm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{varbold}{OMS}{mdugm}{b}{n}
%% Large symbols
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{txex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{txex}{bx}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{varnormal}{OMX}{mdugm}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{varbold}{OMX}{mdugm}{b}{n}

%% Math alphabets, at most 16 families
%% some examples only
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{normal}{OT1}{txr}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{bold}{OT1}{txr}{bx}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{varnormal}{OT1}{mdugm}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{varbold}{OT1}{mdugm}{b}{n}

\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{normal}{OT1}{txr}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{bold}{OT1}{txr}{bx}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{varnormal}{OT1}{mdugm}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{varbold}{OT1}{mdugm}{b}{it}

\usepackage{bm,varbm}

\begin{document}

This is Times font. $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. Math font
\[
  \sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0
\]
and bold math font
{\txboldmath\[
  \sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0
\]}
\[
  \bm{\sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0}
\]
\[
  \varbm{\sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0}
\]

\gmfamily\mdmath
This is Garamond font. $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. Math font
\[
  \sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0
\]
and bold math font
{\mdboldmath\[
  \sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0
\]}
\[
  \bm{\sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0}
\]
\[
  \varbm{\sum_i \int_a^b \left( \frac1{K+1} \oplus\alpha_i \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Times and Garamond maths]

When Times maths is enabled either by default or using `\txmath`, the following happens:

- maths version `normal` is used;
- `\bm` uses Times `bold` maths;
- `\varbm` uses Times `bold` maths.

When Garamond maths is activated using `\mdmath`, the following happens:

- maths version `varnormal` is used;
- `\bm` uses Garamond `varbold` maths;
- `\varbm` uses Garamond `varbold` maths.

Package code (all the legal stuff is just because I copied the `bm.sty` file and just did a few find-and-replace, deleted a few lines and tested it - hence, it is a derived work under the licensing terms and has to be designated as such):

```
%%
%% This is file `varbm.sty',
%%
%% Additions and changes (mostly find and replace)
%% are copyright 2015 Clea F. Rees
%%
%% Code from bm.sty  (see below)
%% bm.sty is copyright 1993-2015
%% The LaTeX3 Project and any individual authors listed elsewhere
%% in this file
%% Copyright 1996 1997 1998 1999 2002 2003 2004 David Carlisle Frank Mittelbach
%% Development of the bm package was commissioned by Y&Y Inc.
%% http://www.yandy.com
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Clea F. Rees.
%
% This work consists of the file varbm.sty.
%
% The file varbm.sty is a derived work under the terms of the
% LPPL. It is based on bm.sty dated 2014/10/28 v1.1c which is part of The
% Standard LaTeX `Tools Bundle'. A copy of that work, including the
% unmodified version of bm.sty is available from http://ctan.org/pkg/bm.
%
%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{varbm}
          [2015/08/02 v0.00001 Variable Bold Symbol Support]
\def\varbm#1#2{%
  \let\varbm@pmb\install@mathalphabet
  \let\varbm@pmb@\getanddefine@fonts
  \let\varbm@pmb@@\or
  \edef\varbm@general{\f@encoding/\f@family/\f@series/\f@shape/\f@size}%
  \@tempcnta#2%
  \count@-\count18%
  \advance\count@-\@tempcnta
  \advance\count@15\relax
  \ifnum\count@<\z@
    \advance\@tempcnta\count@
  \fi
  \let\or\relax
  \expandafter\let\csname varbm@#1table\endcsname\@gobble
  \def\varbm@define##1{%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname varbm@#1table\endcsname{%
      \csname varbm@#1table\endcsname\or##1}}%
  \def\getanddefine@fonts##1##2{%
    \def\@tempa{##2}%
    \def\@tempb####1##1####2####3\@nil{\def\@tempb{####2}}%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \@tempb\csname mv@#1\endcsname\@nil
    \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
      \varbm@define\m@ne
    \else
      \edef\@tempa{sym#1\expandafter\@gobblefour\string##1}%
      \ifnum\@tempcnta<%
           \expandafter\ifx\csname\@tempa\endcsname\relax
             \@ne
           \else
             \m@ne
           \fi
        \varbm@define\z@
      \else
        \expandafter\ifx\csname\@tempa\endcsname\relax
          \begingroup
          \escapechar\m@ne
          \edef\@tempb{\endgroup
            \noexpand\split@name
            \expandafter\string\@tempb}%
          \@tempb/\@nil
         \expandafter\ifx
           \csname symvarbold\expandafter\@gobblefour\string##1\endcsname
           \relax
            \expandafter\new@mathgroup\csname\@tempa\endcsname
            \expandafter\new@symbolfont\csname\@tempa\endcsname
                       \f@encoding\f@family\f@series\f@shape
            \advance\@tempcnta\m@ne
         \else
           \def\varbm@expand####1##1####2####3\@nil{\def\varbm@expand{####2}}%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
           \varbm@expand\csname mv@varbold\endcsname\@nil
           \ifx\varbm@expand\@tempb
             \expandafter\let\csname\@tempa\expandafter\endcsname
                \csname symvarbold\expandafter
                        \@gobblefour\string##1\endcsname
           \else
             \expandafter\new@mathgroup\csname\@tempa\endcsname
             \expandafter\new@symbolfont\csname\@tempa\endcsname
                       \f@encoding\f@family\f@series\f@shape
             \advance\@tempcnta\m@ne
           \fi
         \fi
        \else
          \PackageInfo{varbm}%
            {Symbol font \@tempa\space already defined.\MessageBreak
             Not overwriting it}%
        \fi
        \count@\csname\@tempa\endcsname
        \advance\count@-##1%
        \varbm@define{\the\count@\relax}%
      \fi
    \fi}%
  \let\install@mathalphabet\@gobbletwo
  \mv@normal
  \expandafter\xdef\csname varbm@#1table\endcsname{%
    \noexpand\ifcase\@tempcnta
      \csname varbm@#1table\endcsname
    \noexpand\else
      \z@
    \noexpand\fi}%
  \expandafter\split@name\varbm@general\@nil
  \let\install@mathalphabet\varbm@pmb
  \let\getanddefine@fonts\varbm@pmb@
  \let\or\varbm@pmb@@}
\ifx\varbmmax\@undefined
  \chardef\varbmmax=4
\fi
\ifx\mv@varbold\@undefined
  \def\varbm@varboldtable{\m@ne}
  \AtEndOfPackage{%
    \def\varbm@gr@up#1#2{%
      \varbm@pmb{#2}}}
\else
  \varbm{varbold}\varbmmax
  \@ifundefined{symvarboldoperators}
    {}
    {\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet\mathbf{varboldoperators}}
\fi
\begingroup
\catcode`\'=\active
\@firstofone{\endgroup
\def\varbm@general#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \begingroup
    \let\varbm\@firstofone
    \global\let\varbm@command\@empty
    \let\@let@token\@empty
    \let\protect\@empty
    \let\@typeset@protect\@empty
    \def\varbm@mathchoice{\varbm@m@thchoice#1}%
    \def\varbm@group{\varbm@gr@up#1}%
    \let\varbm@table#2%
    \let\left\holdinginserts
    \let\right\left
    \let\mskip\mkern
    \let\hskip\kern
    \let\varbm@prime\copy
    \def'{\varbm@prime\prime\relax}%
    \def\@ifnextchar##1##2##3##4{%
      \if##1##4%
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \fi
      {##2##4}{##3{##4}}}%
    \def\GenericWarning##1##2{%
      \unvcopy{\GenericWarning{##1}{##2}}}%
    \def\GenericError##1##2##3##4{%
      \unvcopy{\GenericError{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}}}%
    \let\DN@\copy
    \let\FN@\copy
    \let\next@\copy
    \global\let\varbm@first\@empty
    \ifx\uproot@\undefined\else
       \def\root##1\of##2{{\root##1\of{##2}}}%
    \fi
    \def\mathaccentV##1{\mathaccent"\accentclass@}%
    \let\@ifnext\@ifnextchar
    \let\measure@lhs\copy
    \let \rel@break\copy
    \let \bin@break\copy
    \let \after@open\copy
    \let \after@close\copy
    \let\ifmmode\iftrue
     \let\install@mathalphabet\def
     \let\getanddefine@fonts\@gobbletwo
     #3%
    \def\select@group##1##2##3##4{{%
      \protect##1{##4}}}%
    \def\use@mathgroup##1##2##3{{%
      \protect\use@mathgroup##1{##2}{##3}}}%
    \varbm@expand#5\varbm@end
  \endgroup
  #4}
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\varbm{%
  \varbm@general\varboldmath\varbm@varboldtable\mv@varbold\varbm@command}
\protected@edef\varbm#1{\varbm{#1}}
\def\DeclareBoldMathCommand{\@testopt\varbm@declare{varbold}}
\def\varbm@declare[#1]#2{%
  \expandafter\varbm@general
        \csname #1math\expandafter\endcsname
        \csname varbm@#1table\expandafter\endcsname
        \csname mv@#1\endcsname
        {\varbm@define#2}}
\def\varbmdefine{\DeclareBoldMathCommand[varbold]}
\outer\def\varbm@end{\@@end}
\def\varbm@expand{\afterassignment\varbm@exp@nd\count@`\a}
\def\varbm@exp@nd{\afterassignment\varbm@test\count@`\a}
\def\varbm@test{%
  \let\varbm@previous\@let@token
  \futurelet\@let@token\varbm@test@}
\def\varbm@test@{%
  \ifx\@let@token\bgroup
    \expandafter\varbm@group
  \else
    \expandafter\varbm@test@token
  \fi}
\def\varbm@gr@up#1#2{%
  \varbm@add{{\varbm@gr@@p#1{{#2}}}}}
\def\varbm@gr@@p#1#2{%
  \ifmmode
    \varbm@mchoice#1{#2}{#2}{#2}{#2}%
  \else
    \bfseries#1#2%
  \fi}
\def\varbm@test@token#1{%
  \let\varbm@next\@empty
  \ifx#1\@@end
  \else\ifx#1\mathchoice
    \let\varbm@next\varbm@mathchoice
  \else\ifx#1\mathchar
    \afterassignment\varbm@mathchar\count@
  \else\ifx#1\mathaccent
    \afterassignment\varbm@mathaccent\count@
  \else\ifx#1\delimiter
    \afterassignment\varbm@delimiter\count@
  \else\ifx#1\radical
    \afterassignment\varbm@radical\count@
  \else\ifx#1\mkern
    \varbm@register#1{\muskip\z@}%
  \else\ifx#1\kern
    \varbm@register#1\skip@
  \else\ifx#1\penalty
    \varbm@register#1\count@
  \else\ifx#1\unvcopy
    \let\varbm@next\varbm@add
  \else\ifcat\noexpand#1\relax
    \xdef\meaning@{\meaning#1}%
    \expandafter\varbm@mchar@test\meaning@""\@nil#1%
  \else\ifcat.\ifcat a#1.\else#1\fi
    \count@\mathcode`#1\relax
    \ifnum\count@=\mathcode`\'%
      \begingroup\uccode`\~`#1\uppercase{\endgroup
        \def\varbm@next{\varbm@expand~}}%
    \else
      \ifx\varbm@previous\left
        \count@\delcode`#1\relax
        \varbm@delimiter
      \else
        \varbm@mathchar
      \fi
    \fi
  \else
    \varbm@add{#1}%
  \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
  \varbm@next}
\def\varbm@define#1{%
  \begingroup
    \ifx\varbm@command\@gtempa
      \def\mathchar{\global\mathchardef#1}%
      \varbm@command
    \else
      \toks@\expandafter{\varbm@command}%
      \xdef#1{\varbm@first\noexpand\varbm@protect\noexpand#1{\the\toks@}}%
    \fi
  \endgroup}
\def\varbm@protect#1{%
  \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \else
    \protect#1\expandafter\@gobble
  \fi}
\def\varbm@mchoice#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \mathchoice{\hbox{#1$\displaystyle\m@th#2$}}%
             {\hbox{#1$\textstyle\m@th#3$}}%
             {\hbox{#1$\scriptstyle\m@th#4$}}%
             {\hbox{#1$\scriptscriptstyle\m@th#5$}}}
\def\varbm@m@thchoice#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \varbm@add{\varbm@mchoice#1{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}}
\def\varbm@register#1#2{%
  \def\@tempa{#1\the#2}%
  \afterassignment\varbm@r@gister#2}
\def\varbm@r@gister{%
  \varbm@xadd{\@tempa\space}}
\def\varbm@mathchar{%
  \@tempcntb\count@
  \let\@tempa\varbm@group
  \varbm@changefam{}%
  \ifnum\count@>\@tempcntb
    \ifx\varbm@command\@empty
      \xdef\@gtempa{\mathchar\the\count@\space}%
    \fi
    \varbm@xadd{\mathchar\the\count@\space}%
  \else
    \begingroup
      \divide\count@"1000
      \let\varbm@expand\relax
      \varbm@xadd\varbm@class
    \endgroup
    \edef\@tempb{%
      \noexpand\@tempa{\mathchar\the\count@\space}}%
    \@tempb
  \fi}
\def\varbm@pmb#1{%
  \varbm@add{\varbm@pmb@{#1}}}
\def\varbm@pmb@#1{{%
  \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\m@th\mkern.4mu$}%
  \mathchoice
    \varbm@pmb@@\displaystyle\@empty{#1}%
    \varbm@pmb@@\textstyle\@empty{#1}%
    \varbm@pmb@@\scriptstyle\defaultscriptratio{#1}%
    \varbm@pmb@@\scriptscriptstyle\defaultscriptscriptratio{#1}}}
\def\varbm@pmb@@#1#2#3{{%
  \setbox\z@\hbox{$\m@th#1#3$}%
  \dimen@#2\wd\tw@
  \rlap{\copy\z@}%
  \kern\dimen@
  \raise1.5\dimen@\rlap{\copy\z@}%
  \kern\dimen@
  \box\z@}}%
\def\varbm@class{%
  \ifcase\count@
    \or
    \mathop\or
    \mathbin\or
    \mathrel\or
    \mathopen\or
    \mathclose\or
    \mathpunct\or
  \fi}
\def\varbm@add#1{%
  \begingroup
    \toks@\expandafter{\varbm@command#1}%
    \xdef\varbm@command{\the\toks@}%
  \endgroup
  \varbm@expand}
\def\varbm@xadd#1{%
  \begingroup
    \toks@\expandafter{\varbm@command}%
    \xdef\varbm@command{\the\toks@#1}%
  \endgroup
  \varbm@expand}
\def\varbm@mathaccent{%
 \varbm@changefam{}%
 \begingroup
 \def\varbm@group##1{\endgroup\varbm@xadd{\bgroup}##1\egroup}%
 \def\varbm@test@token{\endgroup\varbm@test@token}%
 \let\relax\@empty
 \varbm@xadd{\mathaccent\the\count@\space}}
\def\varbm@delimiter{%
  \ifnum\count@>\z@
    \varbm@changefam{}%
    \varbm@changefam{000}%
  \fi
  \varbm@xadd{\delimiter\the\count@\space}}%
\def\varbm@radical{%
 \varbm@changefam{}%
 \varbm@changefam{000}%
 \varbm@xadd{\radical\the\count@\space}}%
\edef\varbm@mchar@{\meaning\mathchar}
\def\varbm@mchar@test#1"#2"#3\@nil#4{%
  \xdef\meaning@{#1}%
  \ifx\meaning@\varbm@mchar@
    \count@"#2\relax
    \varbm@mathchar
  \else
    \ifx\varbm@previous\@empty
      \ifx\relax#4%
        \gdef\varbm@first{#4}%
      \fi
    \fi
    \varbm@add{#4}%
  \fi}
\def\varbm@changefam#1{%
  \@tempcnta\count@
  \divide\@tempcnta"1000#1 %
  \multiply\@tempcnta"1000#1 %
  \advance\@tempcnta-\count@
  \divide\@tempcnta-"100#1 %
  \@tempcnta\varbm@table
  \ifnum\@tempcnta=\m@ne
    \let\@tempa\varbm@pmb
  \else
    \multiply\@tempcnta"100#1 %
    \advance\count@\@tempcnta
  \fi}
\def\varbm@prime{^\bgroup
  \let\varbm@prime'%
  \def\prim@s##1\relax{##1\futurelet\@let@token\pr@m@s}%
  \prim@s}
\let\varboldsymbol\varbm
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `varbm.sty'.
```

Comment: Do you know what is happening with the brackets in the second Garamond example?  They appear to be lighter.

Comment: @FreddieWitherden And that's not the worst issue - look at the placement of the lower limit on the integral sign. I thought this might be because `bm` is getting the spacing based on the `normal` version rather than the `varnormal` version. But I can't reproduce it for `\bm` when I set the `bold` version to Garamond but keep `normal` as the default and use `varnormal` for `\mdmath`. I can only reproduce it there for `\hm`. So something is different about the `heavy` set up which I'm getting wrong, compared with `bold`. But I can't currently see *what*.

Comment: @FreddieWitherden [New question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258361/how-can-i-declare-a-heavy-maths-version-without-altering-spacing-and-symbol-choi). I hope I will be able to update my answer here shortly!

Comment: @FreddieWitherden Well, David says that this way of doing it is 'wrong really'. But I wish I could understand *why* since maybe I'd then have some clue what might be a better approach!

Comment: Yes, I don't know enough details about the inner workings of `bm` to know if there is a more effective way.

Comment: @FreddieWitherden See new answer. Probably overkill but it does seem to work.