# Latex into Keynote (Greek Letters Font)

Tags: fonts, greek

i'm preparing a presentation with Keynote. To include the formulas i'm using Latexit but the text and the formulas have  different fonts. I've tried to use this to change the font in Latexit:

```
\usepackage{mathspec}
 \usepackage{xunicode}
 \usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{Chalkboard} 

\setmathsfont(Digits){Chalkboard}
\setmathsfont(Latin){Chalkboard}
\setmathsfont(Greek){Chalkboard}
\setmathsfont(Symbols){Chalkboard}
```

It is working for Digits and Latin, but it isn't for Greek and Symbols.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The Chalkboard font doesn't contain a full set of Greek characters, nor does it have many symbols.  So you'll need to use a different font for the math parts. Probably your best bet is the AMS Euler font.  See [Handwritten font with math support](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28340)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Chalkboard font doesn't contain a full set of Greek characters, nor does it have many symbols. So you'll need to use a different font for the math parts. Probably your best bet is the AMS Euler font. See [Handwritten font with math support](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28340).

By the way, when using XeLaTeX, you shouldn't load `xunicode` and `xltxtra` but just load `fontspec` (or `mathspec`).  The `xltxtra` package is generally no longer required unless you need the specific functionality it offers (like typesetting the XeTeX logo). The `xunicode` package is loaded by `fontspec` and it's best not to load it yourself.