# How to turn a figure into a symbol?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols

I have some figures, for e.g., finite graphs, lattices or knots, that I have drawn in eps (or pdf) format. I would ideally love to have maps indexed by these figures. However, these figures are not part of the usual LaTeX symbol set(s). Is there a way to incorporate this? For example, if I have drawn a trefoil knot and I want to write something like `$f_{trefoil}$` (or perhaps a more complicated code) which upon processing this should look like what I want, what do I need to do?

P.S. Feel free to retag this question as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks for all the great answers. I'll perhaps try out all of them at some point of time.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming that the trefoil picture is in the file `trefoil.pdf` (the extension can be any accepted by the engine you're using), you can define the symbol at various sizes

```
\newcommand{\trefoil}{\ensuremath{%
  \mathchoice{\includegraphics[height=2ex]{trefoil}}
    {\includegraphics[height=2ex]{trefoil}}
    {\includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{trefoil}}
    {\includegraphics[height=1ex]{trefoil}}
}}
```

Then `$f_{\trefoil}+\trefoil$` will do. Adjust the heights to what seems best to you.

It should be noted that `\includegraphics` builds a box that can be used *everywhere*, not only inside `figure` environments. You can see also the **adjustbox** package for more options related to positioning the picture.

Comment: Why can't use this in section environment? @egreg

Comment: @AndreaLeo `\protect\trefoil` when in a moving argument; or replace `\newcommand` with `\DeclareRobustCommand`

Answer (score 4):

You could create your own symbol font as described in [Create a symbol font from SVG symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22487/create-a-symbol-font-from-svg-symbols). For this you can draw these symbols as pictures first and have them placed one per page using the `preview` package. Afterwards turn them into SVG format using a suitable converted like e.g. with [InkScape](http://inkscape.org/) using `inkscape --export-svg file.svg file.pdf`.

When you have the font you can just define named macros for every symbol and use these macros in the equations.

Answer (score 3):

(I wanted to post a picture so need to use the "answer" rather than "comment" section, but this is really just a comment.)

I'm not sure how this would look.  I just tried it with a trefoil and found that `f_{\trefoil}` was quite hard to see that it was a trefoil.

[image: trefoil as subscript]

However, if that is good enough - it's certainly clear that that's a knot and would be distinct from, say, a figure 8 (though not from the other trefoil) - then I did the above using TikZ and it wouldn't be hard to figure out some stylised symbols that at least bore some resemblance to the original diagrams.

But it might be easier simply to scan through the unicode symbols and choose some that looked at least vaguely similar.

Comment: Thanks but the trefoil was perhaps a bad example on my part as I have figures of graphs that are typically not, to the best of my knowledge, part of the unicode symbols.

Comment: @SomnathBasu: The trefoil is not in the unicode list as far as I can tell.  What I did above was take a drawing that I have of the trefoil and reproduce it as a subscript to the `f`.  So I was trying exactly what you described.  It was really just a comment to say, "Are you *sure* that this is what you want to do?".  It is, as egreg says, perfectly *possible*, but I'm questioning the advisability.  That's why this was really meant as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @ Andrew - Sorry for the misunderstanding! I get what you're saying now. But the figures I have are really objects which are not listed in unicode. Other than what you did (or what egreg suggested), what else can I do?

Comment: @SomnathBasu: My unicode suggestion was meaning not to find *exact* correspondences but just suggestive ones.  Really just a more complicated version of "Let \(a\) represent the trefoil, the \(f_a = ...\)".  I just think that unless the drawings are quite simple, it's going to be hard to tell what they are.  But maybe the pictures are sufficiently different that it'll be obvious that this squiggle means the trefoil and that squiggle means the figure 8 - I don't know!  How are you generating these figures?  With TikZ then any of the others' ideas would work.

Answer (score 3):

This answer takes some of the ideas of other answers already posted.

I have used [`autotrace`](http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/) in the past to convert a rasterized image (like JPEG, BMP, PNG, ...) into a vector-based image (like SVG, EPS, AI, FIG, ...). For high-quality rasterized images, the output can be quite good. Of course, this depends on the type of graphic. Moreover, it is a free and quick tool, and is available for [online conversion](http://www.roitsystems.com/cgi-bin/autotrace/tracer.pl). So, you don't have to install a separate application to render a vector-based graphic file. Once you have your EPS output, you can include it using a command definition using [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) (like in @egreg's answer).