# Non-bitmapped "thumb up" symbol for flagging "good practice" tips

Tags: fonts, symbols

I want to use a "thumb up" symbol, to flag a "good practice" tips in my document. Table 244 in the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol list shows that the `dingbat` package provides the following:

[image]

However, the symbol is bitmapped and doesn't render well when zoomed in on, which I dislike:

[image]

**Do you know of a similar, non-bitmapped symbol?** Otherwise Feel free to suggest an alternative symbol that conveys the same meaning.

Comment: Go to FB! `:P` Ok, joke aside, you could create or get a vector graphic and use the picture as a symbol, see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22487 or here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31490

Comment: Obligatory Unicode suggestion: U+1F44D:  (naturally needs a font which includes the glyph)

Comment: You are very well capable of writing up the 8-10 lines in tikz for that. *Rounded corners for the fingers* :P

Comment: Perhaps you could use the package **niceframe-type1**, it has the type1 dingbat font, but unfortunately the package don’t have any practical documentation, so I cannot write an answer with this package (it’s actually a font, not a package, but in CTAN, it’s listed as package).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A free SVG version can be found on Wikimedia: [Symbol thumbs up](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Symbol_thumbs_up.svg).
The file [`Symbols_thumbs_up.svg`](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Symbol_thumbs_up.svg) can be converted with `Inkscape` to PDF like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1048260):

```
inkscape --export-pdf=Symbol_thumbs_up.pdf Symbol_thumbs_up.svg
```

The white margins can be removed by `pdfcrop`:

```
pdfcrop Symbol_thumbs_up.pdf
```

The result is `Symbols_thumbs_up-crop.pdf`.

In LaTeX it can be included, mirrored and resized by package `graphicx` with a driver that supports PDF. Otherwise it can be converted to EPS via `pdftops` of `xpdf` or `poppler`:

```
pdftops -eps Symbols_thumbs_up-crop.pdf Symbols_thumbs_up.eps
```

LaTeX example that defines `\LeftThumbsUp` and `\RightThumbsUp`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\RightThumbsUpAux}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{Ag}%
    \raisebox{-\dp0}{%
      \includegraphics[{%
        height=\dimexpr\dp0+\ht0\relax,
        #1%
      }]{Symbol_thumbs_up-crop.pdf}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\RightThumbsUp}{%
  \RightThumbsUpAux{}%
}
\newcommand*{\RightThumbsDown}{%
  \RightThumbsUpAux{origin=c,angle=180}%
}
\newcommand*{\LeftThumbsUp}{%
  \scalebox{-1}[1]{\RightThumbsUp}%
}
\newcommand*{\LeftThumbsDown}{%
  \scalebox{-1}[1]{\RightThumbsDown}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \LeftThumbsUp    & \verb|\LeftThumbsUp|\\
  \RightThumbsUp   & \verb|\RightThumbsUp|\\
  \LeftThumbsDown  & \verb|\LeftThumbsDown|\\
  \RightThumbsDown & \verb|\RightThumbsDown|
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Just to be picky: The thumb symbols are normally displayed from the agent's perspective, so the thumbs down symbols should have their palms hidden.

Comment: @Sverre My impression from a quick web search was: Most images show the fingers, some shows the front view (front of the thumb), and images with the fingers hidden are quite rare.

Comment: When doing a google images search for "thumbs down", my impression is that the split is about 50-50. I personally prefer the thumbs down symbols where the palm is hidden, since this would be consistent with the visible palm in the thumbs up symbols (= they are all seen from the agent's perspective). But this is a minor point - I just wanted to call your attention to it in case you (or someone else) cared.

Answer (score 14):

The [fontawesome](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome/doc/fontawesome.pdf) package is a good go-to for things like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}\Huge

\faThumbsDown

\faThumbsODown

\faThumbsOUp

\faThumbsUp

\end{document}
```

It does not appear to pixelate even at 400% zoom level in my PDF viewer:

[image: rendered LaTeX]

Answer (score 6):

Create a new character.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\thumbsup{\scalerel*{\includegraphics{up.png}}{O}}
\def\thumbsdown{\scalerel*{\includegraphics{down.png}}{g}}

\begin{document}
thumbs up \thumbsup

thumbs down \thumbsdown
\end{document}
```

0 and g refers to the character used as reference of size and vertical position. For those I tested, the best combination is as it is. Figures up.png and down.png must be attached to your folder.

Of course, if you prefer another thumbsup/down picture, you can change it.

[image: down]

[image: up]

[image: pdf]

Comment: PNG is not vector graphics.

Comment: yeah, but it is still a good solution if you choose a large image. large I mean 150x150 pixels ... , of course it depends with your purposes.

Comment: The solution also works with PDF files containing vector graphics.