# Ear symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

I am looking for an ear symbol, much like the `\eye` in [dingbats](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/dingbat/dingbat.pdf)?
Something like

[image]

would be perfect.

I want to include it into a text like I did with the eye symbol, using it instead of the "hear":

[image]

I could use a normal image and scale it, but it would be easier to use a symbol.

Comment: Please post a picture of that ear instead of the link (and maybe add a minimal example document which shows us how you created your screenshot)! Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are able to use Xe- or LuaLaTeX, you may use the unicode [U+1F442](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f442/index.htm) by copy pasting it in your source code or like in my following MWE:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
    \setmainfont{quivira.otf}
    \symbol{"1F442}
    \setmainfont{symbola.ttf}
    \symbol{"1F442}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When you have found your symbol, you may define a macro as

```
\newcommand*{\ear}{{\fontspec{the_font}\symbol{"1F442}}}
```

---

For PDFLaTeX, you will have to search for other LaTeX-symbols in the [common way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14). But I was not lucky here. If you try to add an image, you may look on posts like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31490).

If my solution works for you, you may possibly want to redefine the eye symbol as well in order to visually fit. This would look like the following:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand*{\ear}{{\fontspec{symbola.ttf}\symbol{"1F442}}}
\newcommand*{\eye}{{\fontspec{symbola.ttf}\symbol{"1F441}}}

\begin{document}
    \section{Do}
    \eye \hspace{1cm} do

    \noindent\ear
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot - this worked perfectly after I figured out that the font is called Symbola and. Or symbola - and that after about ten years with Linux and two with Mac.

Comment: I've tried to do this in overleaf and failed. "The font symbola cant be found"

Comment: @StevenSagona `fontspec` is searching for fonts on your system here. I do not think that this will work in any online editor.
See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377756/32245)  for a possible workaround

Answer (score 16):

Here, I just saved your ear image into a file (ear.pdf and/or ear.eps), and used a scaled `\includegraphics` to insert it.  You can vary the size, which I set to a height of 2ex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,dingbat}
\def\ear{\includegraphics[height=2ex]{ear}}
\begin{document}
Ear and eye symbols: 

\ear{} and \eye
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Nice approach - but I prefer for my case the previous Unicode approach and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Rainer  I'm glad you found something that suits your particular need.