# Changing to custom font on overleaf

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, overleaf

I was trying to use a different font for my resume in LaTeX and after some search the following code seems to be the answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Calibri}

\begin{document}

Hello World

\end{document}
```

Since I'm using Overleaf, I was not able to run it at first, but learned to compile with XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX to be able to use the `fontspec` package.

The problem that I have is that running this code with the setting mentioned above results in Timed Out error. I also tried with LuaLaTeX engine but I get a blank page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please ask the support of overleaf which fonts they have installed ... See also related question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377749/trouble-setting-new-font-in-overleaf

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I found a list of their supported fonts and apparently Calibri is not one of them:https://www.overleaf.com/articles/slash-fontspec-all-the-fonts/qnsxyhrgjsgs

Comment: It's unlikely that Overleaf has the Calibri font, because it is a commercial font which is shipped with Microsoft Office (I think).  You could try to locate the Calibri `otf` or `ttf` font file on your local machine and upload it to your Overleaf project.

Comment: I hesitate to say RTFM since you are new here, but the [Overleaf documentation tells you what fonts they install](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_typefaces).  [Calibri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibri) is not one of them, possibly because it does not have an open source licence.