# Latex Tikz drawing a human ear

Tags: tikz-pgf

Does anyone have some Tikz code for a human ear? I need it for a picture, where sound is coming from the left an hitting an ear on the right.

Maybe someone had already needed this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not `tikz`, but...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,scalerel}
\def\ear{\includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{ear}}
\newcommand\lowparen{\raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\ht\strutbox+.5\dp\strutbox}{)}}
\begin{document}
\scalerel*{%
\scaleto{\lowparen}{2pt}\kern-.1pt%
\scaleto{\lowparen}{3pt}\kern-.3pt%
\scaleto{\lowparen}{4pt}\kern-.5pt%
\scaleto{\lowparen}{5pt}\kern-.7pt%
\scaleto{\lowparen}{6pt}%
}{X}\ear
\end{document}
```

[image]

or reverse the ear:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,scalerel}
\def\ear{\scalebox{-1}[1]{\includegraphics[height=1.8ex]{ear}}}
\newcommand\lowparen{\raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\ht\strutbox+.5\dp\strutbox}{)}}
\begin{document}
\scalerel*{%
\scaleto{\lowparen}{2pt}\kern-.1pt%
\scaleto{\lowparen}{3pt}\kern-.3pt%
\scaleto{\lowparen}{4pt}\kern-.5pt%
\scaleto{\lowparen}{5pt}\kern-.7pt%
\scaleto{\lowparen}{6pt}%
}{X}\ear
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: ear.png image obtained from [Ear symbol in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204012/ear-symbol-in-latex)

[image]

Comment: Steven you are great!+1 for your answer.

Comment: Is there any way to put this into a tikz figure, since I already have a tikzfigure, where I need to insert the ear?

Comment: @mads you could define `\def\soundear{\scalerel*{%
\scaleto{\lowparen}{2pt}\kern-.1pt%
\scaleto{\lowparen}{3pt}\kern-.3pt%
\scaleto{\lowparen}{4pt}\kern-.5pt%
\scaleto{\lowparen}{5pt}\kern-.7pt%
\scaleto{\lowparen}{6pt}%
}{X}\ear}`.  Then, wherever in `tikz` you would otherwise place a printing character, you could instead place `\soundear`.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me. Error message is "file 'ear' not found"

Comment: @StevenSagona Let me look further...the code seems to indicate it was part of the `dingbat` package, but that seems not to me the case.

Comment: @StevenSagona Download the ear image at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204012/ear-symbol-in-latex into the `ear.png` file.