# Looking for symbol: Shield

Tags: symbols

I am looking for a "Shield" symbol:

[image]

I already perused the Comprehensive Latex Symbol List, with the closest fit being `\dsheraldical` from the dictsym package, which is however non-satisfactory because of the diagonal bar - I need both the symbol itself and a strike-through version of the symbol, and that doesn't look good with `\dsheraldical`.

I also tried Detexify, but either my drawing skills suck or such a symbol simply doesn't exist.

Any suggestions - either for where to find that symbol, or how to "create" it through other ways?

**EDIT:** Building on Jake's answer, my solution looks like this:

```
\usepackage{tikz}

% Smaller than Jake's version, which was much larger than other symbols
\newcommand\shield{ \tikz [baseline] \draw (0,1.5ex) -- (0,0.75ex) arc [radius=0.5ex, start angle=-180, end angle=0] -- (1ex,1.5ex) -- cycle; }
% Strikethrough version of the same symbol
\newcommand\struckshield{ \tikz [baseline] \draw (0,1.5ex) -- (0,0.75ex) arc [radius=0.5ex, start angle=-180, end angle=0] -- (1ex,1.5ex) -- cycle (0,0) -- (1.0ex,1.75ex); }
```

Look, Ma, I can do TikZ! :-)

Comment: You can draw it using TikZ and define it as a macro. It is also possible to make your own font with it, see [Create a symbol font from SVG symbols](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22487/create-a-symbol-font-from-svg-symbols).

Comment: Another Package of use can be: [PSTricks -> pst-circ](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-circ/) Logical circuit symbols can be found in Chapter 3 under the _Contents_.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could, of course, use TikZ for this:

[image]

The symbol will scale with your font size, since it uses `ex` to define the path.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\shield{%
    \tikz [baseline] \draw (0,1.75ex) -- (0,0.75ex) arc [radius=0.75ex, start angle=-180, end angle=0] -- (1.5ex,1.75ex) -- cycle;%
}

A shield: \shield
\end{document}
```

---

If you're feeling fancy, you could parametrise it a bit:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\shield[1][]{%
\tikzset{
    shield width/.store in=\shieldwidth,
    shield width=1.5ex,
    shield height/.store in=\shieldheight,
    shield height=1.75ex
}%
\tikz [baseline,#1] \draw (0,\shieldheight) -- (0,\shieldwidth/2) arc [radius=\shieldwidth/2, start angle=-180, end angle=0] -- (\shieldwidth,\shieldheight) -- cycle;%
}

A shield: \shield

A wide shield: \shield[shield width=2ex]

A tall shield: \shield[shield height=3ex]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could make a new box for the shield, save the tikz shield inside that, and define a new command `\shield` which just copies that box. I guess it'd be a bit lighter that way if the shield is used frequently.

Comment: @morbusg: That sounds like a good idea, but I've never done anything with boxes. Would you care to add a new answer or edit this one to show how to do that?

Comment: Jake, @morbusg: Also check out my `storebox` package which takes care that such repeated content is only stored once in the output PDF. However, for a small drawing like this it might not be that important.

Comment: It could just be something like: `\newbox\shieldbox\setbox\shieldbox=\hbox{\tikz\draw<...>}\def\shield{\copy\shieldbox}` and after that one could use it with `\shield`.

Comment: You should use `\usebox` instead of `\copy` to make sure horizontal mode is entered first.

Comment: Oh, nevermind about the new box, it couldn't scale with the font size.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: yeah or prefix with `\leavevmode`

Comment: @morbusg: You could add a `\resizebox` or `\scalebox` with a font size dependent factor.

Comment: Very, very nice and helpful answer. But I actually prefer Count Zero's solution, since it doesn't require TikZ plus a macro.

Comment: @DevSolar: Agreed, Count Zero's solution is definitely the way to go for this.

Comment: @Jake: As per comment to Count Zero, while his solution has a certain appeal, `milstd` gave me trouble... since I am completely new to TikZ, would you mind showing me how to create a strikethrough-version of the shield? (Horizontal line would be nice, diagonal bottom-left-to-top-right would be perfect.)

Comment: @Jake: Nevermind, I figured it out.

Answer (score 15):

There is another way to do that: in the [`milstd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/logic) package there is a symbol (in fact a rotated logical AND gate), which in fact has a completely different signification, but looks like what you need: `\ANDd`:

[image]

Comment: Ah, nice, that's the way to go. How did you find that?

Comment: @Jake: Got good visual memory. `;)`

Comment: Bwahahaha... *VERY* nice. Wouldn't have thought of that. :-D

Comment: Putting this to the test uncovered some problems with the (apparently ancient) `milstd` package, while the more complex TikZ answer worked out of the box... sorry but while I very much like your solution, the checkmark of approval goes to the answer that actually floats my boat. ;-)

Comment: For the record: It's [this `milstd` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/logic) by Rick Simpson, not [the other `milstd` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/milstd) by Kent McPherson which I tried first and failed `:-)`

Comment: Hm... could still use installation instructions. I fail miserably at getting it installed. TeXLive doesn't have it, manual install fails to work so far. Best I got is "Font \milstd=milstd not loadable: metric data not found or bad."...

Comment: @DevSolar Download [the package](http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/logic.zip) and extract it into a folder where TeX can find it (e. g. put the three files `milstd.mf/.sty/.tex` in your working directory). Afterwards, you can use it like this: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{milstd}
\begin{document}
\ANDd
\end{document}`

Comment: @diabonas: Thanks' I wasn't aware there were two of them... I added the link to my answer, hope it's ok. `:)`

Comment: @diabonas: I use TeXLive on both Linux and Windows. Putting into working directory doesn't work ("milstd.sty not found"). Putting into `texmf-local/tex/latex` and calling `texhash` doesn't work ("Font \milstd=milstd not loadable: metric data not found or bad.").

Answer (score 3):

I need a shield symbol and Jake's answer inspired me. I share my tikz code for my shield [image: shield] here:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz,pifont}

\newcommand\shield{
\tikz [baseline] \draw (3ex,2.5ex) -- (1.5ex,3ex) -- (0ex,2.5ex)  to [out=-90, in=165] (1.5ex,0ex) to [out=15, in=-90] cycle (1.5ex,1.5ex) node {\ding{51}};}

\begin{document}

\shield

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the record, a `tikz`-free solution using the `\fontawesome5` icon package, `\faShield*` command.

[image]