# Symbol for cube

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I've searched the Internet, but got nothing. In LaTeX, we can use `\square` for square, but how can we get a cube, I want to use it in an equation. Here is the picture:

[image: example of equation with cube]

Comment: You can add a link to the image, then someone with enough rep can add the `!` in front of it to make it an image. I think it would help to see an example.

Comment: See if the answer to this question can be adapted to your liking: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38757/looking-for-symbol-shield

Comment: In case of confusion, check [The conprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)

Comment: TikZ'ing it: `\tikz\draw (0,0,0) rectangle (1,1,0) (0,1,0) -- (0,1,-1) -- (1,1,-1) --(1,1,0) (1,0,0) -- (1,0,-1) -- (1,1,-1);`

Comment: Out of curiosity: where did you see this explicit notation for a cube ?

Comment: Answering my own comment: The font used (Euler) led me to the book by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik, [Contrete Mathematics](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics), where this equation is on page 44

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `manfnt` package offers `\mancube` and `\manimpossiblecube`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{manfnt}

\begin{document}

\mancube

\manimpossiblecube

\end{document}
```

[image]

Those commands won't directly work in math mode, but you can use a `\mbox`; something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage{manfnt}

\begin{document}

\[
  \mbox{\mancube}_{n} +(n+1)^{3}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you could define a command if you are going to use the cube several times:

```
\newcommand*\cube{\mbox{\mancube}}
```

Comment: @TorbjørnT. you're right. Boxing the cube (as in `\mbox{\mancube}`) you can use it in math mode.

Comment: Perhaps you could add that to your answer as well.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. right again ;-) Done!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: You may want to add something like `\newcommand{\cube}{\mathord{\mbox{\mancube}}}` to your example.

Comment: @Tobi A safer way might be using `\text` of `amsmath`; `\mathord` is not needed anyway: a box in math mode is always an ordinary symbol.

Comment: @Tobi good idea; thanks. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Congrats on keeping the very same font as the OP used :-)