# Looking for symbol: Fire

Tags: macros, symbols, tikz-styles, tikzsymbols

I am looking for a "Fire" symbol:
Like this, or more minimalistic:

[image]

I found this code for a Shield, and thought that maybe you could make a Fire symbol that way?

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \begin{document}
  \newcommand\shield{%
  \tikz [baseline] \draw (0,1.75ex) -- (0,0.75ex) arc [radius=0.75ex, start 
   angle=-180, end angle=0] -- (1.5ex,1.75ex) -- cycle;%
   }

   A shield: \shield
   \end{document}
```

Link: [Looking for symbol: Shield](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38757/looking-for-symbol-shield)

The code for the Shield gives this output:

[image]

Any suggestions - either for where to find a Fire symbol, or how to "create" it through other ways?

Comment: If you can save your fire image as a graphic, then the answer to this question could be of use, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224357/create-latex-symbol-from-vector-graphics

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the free [OpenSansEmoji](https://github.com/MorbZ/OpenSansEmoji) font and XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\emojifont{OpenSansEmoji} % https://github.com/MorbZ/OpenSansEmoji
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emoji}{\emojifont}
\begin{document}
\Huge\emoji{}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 9):

A `tikzsymbols` option and extreme overkill in the form of a `.pic`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,backgrounds,positioning}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\tikzsymbolsset{%
  after-symbol={},
}
\pgfdeclareradialshading[fradialcolour1,fradialcolour2,fradialcolour3]{fncyradial}{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}{% manual 1082-1083; later - shading is assumed to be 100bp diameter ??
  color(0)=(fradialcolour1);
  color(20bp)=(fradialcolour2);
  color(40bp)=(fradialcolour3);
  color(50bp)=(fradialcolour3)
}
\tikzset{%
  fradial/.code={%
        \tikzset{%
          fancy radial/.cd,
          shading=fncyradial,
          #1
        }
  },
  fancy radial/.search also={/tikz},
  fancy radial/.cd,
  fancy radial inner colour/.code={
        \colorlet{fradialcolour1}{#1}
  },
  fancy radial mid colour/.code={
        \colorlet{fradialcolour2}{#1}
  },
  fancy radial outer colour/.code={
        \colorlet{fradialcolour3}{#1}
  },
  fancy radial inner colour=black,
  fancy radial outer colour=black,
  fancy radial mid colour=white,
  inner color/.style={
        fancy radial inner colour=#1,
  },
  outer color/.style={
        fancy radial outer colour=#1,
  },
  mid color/.style={
        fancy radial mid colour=#1,
  },
}
\tikzset{
  tan/.pic={%
    \path (0,0) [out angle=0, save Hobby path={ff1}, curve through={(.4,.5) (.175,1)}] to (0,1.5)  (0,1.5) [in angle=180, curve through={(-.175,1) (-.4,.5)}, save Hobby path=ff2] to (0,0);
    \path (0,0) [out angle=0, save Hobby path=ff3, curve through={(.2,.25) (.1,.65)}] to (0,1)  (0,1) [in angle=180, curve through={(-.1,.65) (-.2,.25)}, save Hobby path=ff4] to (0,0);
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box/.expanded=#1, blend mode=hard light]%
      \foreach \i/\j/\k [count=\n from 1, evaluate=\n as \m using {isodd(\n) ? (9-\n) : (-10+\n)}, remember=\i as \ilast, remember=\j as \jlast, remember=\k as \klast] in {%
        DarkOrange1/Firebrick2/Firebrick4,% 1 -8
        DarkGoldenrod1/Red2/Sienna4,% 2 8
        Orange1/Red1/DarkOrange3,% 3 -6
        Gold2/RedOrange/Red4,% 4 6
        Goldenrod1/DarkOrange1/Tomato1,% 5 -4
        Gold1/Orange2/DarkRed,% 6 4
        Orange1/OrangeRed1/Red1,% 7 -2
        Gold/BurntOrange/OrangeRed,% 8 2
        yellow/orange/red% 9 0
      }%
      {%
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]%
          \shade [%
          fradial={inner color=\i, outer color=\k, mid color=\j}, scale={.8+2*\n/90}, rotate around={\m:(0,-15mm)}, rotate={\m}] (0,0) [restore and use Hobby path={ff1}{}] [restore and use Hobby path={ff2}{}];
        \end{scope}%
        \pgfsetadditionalshadetransform{\pgftransformyshift{-5mm}}%
        \shade [inner color=\i, outer color=\k, opacity=.75, scale={.75+3.5*\n/90}, rotate around={{-1.25*\m}:(0,-15mm)}, rotate={-1.25*\m}] (0,0) [restore and use Hobby path={ff3}{}] [restore and use Hobby path={ff4}{}];
      }%
    \end{scope}%
  },
}
\begin{document}
\Fire
\tikz{\pic {tan=t};}
\end{document}
```

[image: fires]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429862/4427 if the code raises an error.

Comment: As for `manual 1082-1083; later - shading is assumed to be 100bp diameter ??`: I believe that these are simply hard coded distances. That's it. No auto adjustment to the shape one is shading. So if the shape is too small, the `mid color` will effectively become the outer color.

Answer (score 8):

The `fontawesome` package provides `\faFire`, which 'resembles' a bonfire ;-)

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikzsymbols}
 \usepackage{fontawesome}
 \begin{document}
 \faFire\ needs a \faFireExtinguisher

  And there is \Fire from \texttt{tikzsymbols}
 \end{document}
```

[image]