# How can i draw this shape using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw the image shown below

[image]

can someone help me to draw such image till now i have tried so far
Here is my MWE

```
 \PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,x11names}{xcolor}
 \documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}

 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

 \draw[red,very thick] (-2,0).. controls ++(-0.3,1.1) and ++(0.2,1.2)..(2,0)..controls ++(-0.5,-0.5) and ++(-0.5,-0.1)..(0.5,-.5)..controls ++(-0.8,-0.1) and ++(-0.2,0.1)..(-2,0)..controls ++(2.2,-5) and ++(-0.1,-0.5)..(2,0);
   \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make use of [@cfr's fancy radial shading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372682/121799).

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,x11names}{xcolor}
 \documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\pgfdeclareradialshading[fradialcolour1,fradialcolour2,fradialcolour3]{fncyradial}{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}{% manual 1082-1083; later - shading is assumed to be 100bp diameter ??
  color(0)=(fradialcolour1);
  color(20bp)=(fradialcolour2);
  color(40bp)=(fradialcolour3);
  color(50bp)=(fradialcolour3)
}
\tikzset{%
  fradial/.code={%
        \tikzset{%
          fancy radial/.cd,
          shading=fncyradial,
          #1
        }
  },
  fancy radial/.search also={/tikz},
  fancy radial/.cd,
  fancy radial inner colour/.code={
        \colorlet{fradialcolour1}{#1}
  },
  fancy radial mid colour/.code={
        \colorlet{fradialcolour2}{#1}
  },
  fancy radial outer colour/.code={
        \colorlet{fradialcolour3}{#1}
  },
  fancy radial inner colour=black,
  fancy radial outer colour=black,
  fancy radial mid colour=white,
  inner color/.style={
        fancy radial inner colour=#1,
  },
  outer color/.style={
        fancy radial outer colour=#1,
  },
  mid color/.style={
        fancy radial mid colour=#1,
  },
}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade[bottom color=red,top color=red!50!black] (-2,0) parabola[bend pos=0.5] bend +(0,-2.4)  +(4,0);
    \shade[fradial={inner color=red!50, outer color=red!30!black, mid color=red}] (0,0) circle (2 and 0.5);
    \clip(0.2,3) to[out=-60,in=0] (0,-0.4) to[out=180,in=-145] cycle;
    \shade [%
          fradial={inner color=yellow, outer color=red, mid color=orange}] 
          (-1.2,-1.4) rectangle (1.2,3);          
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]