# How to achieve this symbol in latex

Tags: math-mode, fonts

[image]

Probably it's kind of stupid question, but how do you come up with this symbol in latex

Comment: `$\mathcal{R}$` should do it.

Comment: `\mathcal{R}`? Just a guess.

Comment: @samcarter, seems we had the same idea =)

Comment: @heather But I am simply too slow :)

Comment: @samcarter, I wouldn't say too slow...its just luck, really. =)

Comment: @fudu Anyway, if this does not produce the comment you want, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), so we see what fonts etc your are using.

Comment: In general you go to the Comprehensive LaTeX Sybol List https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/?lang=en

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186779/identifying-a-single-math-symbol

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{R}$
\end{document}
```

produces the desired glyph.

Comment: I am just curious, based on my detextify-screenshot shown below: is there any difference between using `$\mathcal{R}$` with and without the package `amssymb`?

Comment: @Matsmath -- although `\mathcal` originally required `amsfonts` (loaded by `amssymb`), the command was added as a "robust" command to the basic latex document classes, presumably after complaints that the non-robust form was causing problems in titles and other headings.

Answer (score 2):

Your *probably kind of stupid question* (sic!, see OP) deserves a probably kind of stupid answer. Website [link](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

[image]