# How to load specific single glyph associated to \mathscr{\altr} from MathTime Pro 2?

Tags: fonts, symbols, mathtime

I have the official MathTimePro 2 Complete fontset and would like to access, from a normal LaTeX document, one of its very specific glyphs, namely \mathscr{\altr}, without having to load the whole font set...

I was able to do that for \mathscr{r}, following the post:

[Identifying a single math symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186779/identifying-a-single-math-symbol)

via my adapted MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mt2ms}{\skewchar\font42}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mt2ms}{m}{n}{<-7>mt2mcf<7-9>mt2mcs<9->mt2mct}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MTPcurly}{U}{mt2ms}{m}{n}    
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cobhamclass}{0}{MTPcurly}{'114}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\scriptr}{0}{MTPcurly}{'162}

\begin{document}

A set of strings is in the class $\cobhamclass_{*}$ if and only if 
$A$ is \dots within time $P(n)$, for some polynomial $P(n)$.    

And then $\scriptr$.
\end{document}
```

I was able to understand (part of) the preamble commands by reading subsections 7.5.7 and 7.10.7 of Mittelbach & Goossens, "The LaTeX Companion, 2nd. ed.". After consulting Table 11 of [MathTimeProfessional II fonts with LaTeX](https://www.pctex.com/files/managed/1/1b/mtpro2Abbrev.pdf), I then ran

```
latex nfssfont
```

with the input:

```
\currfontname=
\encoding=U
\family=mt2ms
\series=m
\shape=it
\size=
\action=\table \bye
```

I was able to identify the slot for the script r glyph ('162). Unfortunately, however, in the generated table, there did not appear the alternate r glyph, which is the one I am really interested in :-).

I would much appreciate if anyone could show me how to access this specific glyph, by finding its appropriate slot ("code"), and then changing the MWE above accordingly.

Thanks in advance

PS: I would rather compile everything with usual pdflatex, without using, if possible, LuaLatex or XeLaTeX. Otherwise, I would have to learn these new engines, though this might not be such a big deal...

PS2: @cfr I would like to provide another larger guide for MathTimePro, straight from PCTeX's site:
[MTPro guide](https://www.pctex.com/files/managed/f/f5/guide2.pdf). Finally, a MWE showing how to use the glyph I want in a normal document is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[mtpscr]{mtpro2}
% a chamada da variante \altr, nas versoes ``normal'' e ``negrita'', realiza-se, respectivamente, pelos comandos: \mathscr{\altr} e mathbscr{\altr}, sempre em modo matematico

\newcommand{\bvec}[1]{\ensuremath{\vec{\mathbold{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\ensuremath{\hat{\mathbold{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\bvecaltr}{\ensuremath{\vec{\mathbscr{\altr}}}}
\newcommand{\uvecaltr}{\ensuremath{\hat{\mathbscr{\altr}}}}

\begin{document}
    
A solution using the package \texttt{mtpro2} for reproducing the notation à la Griffiths. It seems to be compatible with the package \texttt{amsmath}.
    \[
    \mathscr{\altr}
    \]
    
    \[
    \bvec{\mathscr{\altr}}=\vec{\mathscr{\altr}}
    \]
    
    \[
    \bvecaltr, \uvecaltr
    \]
    
    
    \begin{align}
        \bvec{F} &= \dfrac{qq'}{\mathscr{\altr}^2}\,\uvecaltr \\
        &= \dfrac{qq'}{\mathscr{\altr}^3}\,\bvecaltr \\
        &= \dfrac{qq'}{|\mathbold{r} - \mathbold{r}'|^3}\,(\mathbold{r}-\mathbold{r}')
    \end{align}
    
    \begin{align}
        \int_{\mathcal{R}} f(\mathscr{\altr})\,d\mathcal{V}
    \end{align}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: How would you typeset these characters if using this set of fonts for your document generally? If they don't appear in the tables, they are not part of those particular fonts. That is, they are not provided by that encoding, family, shape etc. They way you'd typeset them normally should enable you to trace back to which font they are provided by (if any).

Comment: The document you linked is truncated, so all implementation details are missing. If you have the original document, you can likely find out what it is doing by searching for the relevant command names. All it says right now is that the alt macros only work when the corresponding fonts are assigned to the appropriate maths alphabets. You need the implementation details in the missing part of that documentation.

Comment: I have edited my original question, with a new postscript (PS2) in order to give the information @cfr demanded

Comment: Sorry, but the publisher appears to have deliberately provided only documentation lacking implementation details and their licence prohibits users from sharing the support files (and not just the fonts). So I think you need somebody who has purchased the fonts or to ask the company for support. As far as I can tell, it's not possible to determine the information you need from publicly available information. This seems to be a choice on the part of the company. It's not unusual to restrict the distribution of fonts. What's less usual are the restrictions on the support package.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue. It was due to a careless look at the table generated by the command:

```
latex ntfss
```

It does have the glyph I wanted listed with the code '062. It is then just a matter of adapting my original MWE and it works now perfectly.
Thanks